# UILabel size changes when scrolling in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` which I am overwriting. It has a property called `nameLabel` of type `UILabel`. I set initialize it without a `frame` and set the `numberOfLines` to 3.

```
let nameLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.numberOfLines = 3
label.sizeToFit()
return label
}()
```

The name label has the following VFL constraint applied to it:

```
   addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0]-10-[v1]-10-|", views: nameLabel, userLabel)
```

where `addConstraintsWithFormat` is defined as the following from Brian Voong's UICollectionView example:

```
extension UIView {
 func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
for (index, view) in views.enumerate() {
  let key = "v\(index)"
  viewsDictionary[key] = view
  view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options:   NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
 }
}
```

What happens is, say I have one cell whose `nameLabel` text is rendered in three lines (enough lines to merit three lines of wrapping, given the constraints).

So what happens is, I scroll to that cell, it shows the `nameLabel` as having three lines, I scroll past that cell. When I scroll back up to that cell, the very same `UILabel` now has one line.

How can I keep the flexible display of the `UILabel` size based on the content it renders?

Comment: That's probably because of '.sizeToFit' which requires base frame/bound, based from your initialization that behavior was expected.. And the solution is redeclare the frame of your label before calling 'sizeToFit'.

Comment: Unfortunately redeclaring the frame does not change the behavior.

Comment: Can you post some lines from your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` delegate showing your implementation of that `UILabel`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your error, implementing it the way you have above makes the error...

I didn't see how you implemented it inside your `-cellForItemAtIndexPath` though, Fixed it with some modification from what you have provided, here is my `-cellForItemAtIndexPath` looks like:

```
//--
// UICollectionView Delegates
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cvCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // just to remove multi existence of identical views
    //
    cell.subviews.forEach { (view) in
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        // declare constant configurations here
        //
        label.numberOfLines = 3
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "Index: \(indexPath.row)\n and this is quite a long text that will occuply 3 lines"

        return label
    }()

    // this is just an example base frame
    //
    nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width/*your width*/, CGFloat.max)
    nameLabel.sizeToFit()

    cell.addSubview(nameLabel)

    // ...
    //
    // updates constraints here 

    return cell
}
```

Hope this would help you.. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thank you for this! I think this works too! I changed what I was doing, and found a solution which also worked, which is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the error but setting Visual Format Strings of Auto Layout Constraints.

I hadn't applied the horizontal constraint, neither had I given the `UILabel` a fixed width. My new constraints are the following:

```
  addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-20-[v0(200)]", views:nameLabel)
  addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0]-10-[v1]-10-|", views: nameLabel, userLabel)
```

where as before I only had

```
  addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0]-10-[v1]-10-|", views: nameLabel, userLabel)
```

I didn't use `sizeToFit()` at all. Only the following were my `UILabel` settings in my `UICollectionViewCell` class.

```
 let nameLabel: UILabel = {
  let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
  label.numberOfLines = 3
  label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
  let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20.0)
  label.font = font
  return label
 }()
```

and then I set the text later in the class

```
 nameLabel.text = name
```